# Route messages based on service instance unique id

Tags: redis, jms, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe, spring-jms

I have multiple instances of service A deployed where each service produces the request X events to SQS, which triggers the lambda functions and produces the various response events for that request submitted by particular service A instance. I would like to deliver these response events stored in a ActiveMQ topic such that each service A instance should only get the response events of a request it is submitted to queue. I can scale the number of service A instances horizontally.

For example, I have 2 instances of service A named instance1 & instance2. the instance1 submits the request to SQS with request id 1 and the instance2 submits the request to same SQS with request id 2 (request id is unique). The SQS will trigger the lambda functions, will produces the response events for request id 1 & 2 after lambda processing, stores them in a ActiveMQ topic (single one). The instance 1 & 2 are subscribers for this topic and the instance 1 should only get the response events of the request 1 and similary for instance 2.

Can we write a filtering logic for this? or can we fulfil this with Redis pub-sub? Kindly help.

Comment: You've solicited "suggestions" here which means that the answer you accept is going to be based on opinion. Such questions are off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You eliminated the specific solicitation for suggestions, but the basic character of the question hasn't changed. You're left with 2 questions that can be answered with a simple "yes" or "no." Assuming you don't actually want such a simplistic answer one can safely assume you want an explanation of _how_ to write filtering logic or fulfill this with Redis. The answers you get are going to have a unique set of pros and cons and therefore ultimately the one you pick will based on opinion. As noted previously, questions like this are off topic here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a request-reply pattern. There are several patterns for doing request and reply with ActiveMQ.

1. Shared request destination, separate response destination(s)
2. Shared request destination, shared response destination(s)
3. Separate request destination, separate response destination(s)

For #1:

i. Producer sets up a consumer on the response queue (or topic)
ii. Publish requests to a queue (or topic)
iii. Set the name of the response queue (or topic) in the JMSReplyTo header on the message
iv. Consumer receives the request, processes the messages and publishes response to queue (or topic) based on the value from the JMSReplyTo header

For #2:

i. Producer sets up a consumer on the response queue (or topic) using a *selector* to match the message based on a header value
ii. Publish requests to a queue (or topic)
iii. Consumer receives the request, processes the messages and publishes response to queue (or topic) and sets a value for the header field on the message

For #3:

.. basically the same as the others, but w/ separate request queues.

#1 is generally the most scalable, observable, and preferred option. You can also use 'disappearing' queues for request & response queues using ActiveMQ's destination garbage collection (esp useful for option #3).

Important-- you mentioned 'topic' and 'storing messages'. Keep in mind that topics do not store messages by default in ActiveMQ. You may want a queue instead.

Comment: Thank you @Mat Pavlovich. Yes topic(s) won't store messages by default but requirement is smart pub-sub, instead of getting all messages from topic to subscribers, only get the subset of messages as mentioned above. Looks like message selectors are one way to do it but it has its own cost associated with it (depends on client/server side filtering, vendor specific implementation).